Is it possible to turn Mars into a habitable planet with unlimited source of electricity?
Assuming that there is an unlimited source of electricity in a small box and connecting the unlimited current to planet Mars's surface (DC current), and warming up the planet (by circulating current and electrical resistivity in Mars's core) also turning it's frozen water into oxygen and hydrogen by electrolysis automatically, does the planet become habitable like earth or by one strong electrostatic lightning all the hydrogen and oxygen turn into water vapor by a big worldwide explosion? or the lightning only turn a small portion of hydrogen and oxygen into vapor in a local area?

If you had an unlimited source of electricity, I think there would be much more interest in using it for purposes other than terraforming Mars. However, other physical issues would arise, as an infinite amount of electricity in a finite space would create a black hole and lead to other problems related to entropy.

I think this is more of a question for Worldbuilding.SE since, as per the above comment, it relies on violating the known laws of physics.

I suspect this is an 'everybody dies' scenario. The short answer is no.

Even ignoring all the issues with running DC current through an entire planet, a stoichiometric mix of hydrogen and oxygen is going to be extremely flammable, obviously. Even in the absence of any ignition source, the hydrogen will react with free oxygen at a slow rate, so you'd have to somehow capture or react the hydrogen to make the planet stay oxygenated in the long term.
